# Generate statements for LRS in Android

Tags: android, tin-can-api, lrs

I have to send information to a LRS retrieved from some xAPI content using an Android application. Is there some libraries or "best practices" that helps to create these statements?

Answer (score 1):

There is TinCanJava which is an open source library that should work on Android. It implements the data model and LRS communication for xAPI. Find it here:

http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanJava/

There is also the TinCanAndroid-Offline library which leverages the above, though it is getting a bit dated. I would suggest anyone looking at it take a close look at the source to understand it, and perhaps implement some of the functionality themselves. It is available at:

https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanAndroid-Offline

Comment: Thank for the answer. Where can I find some example of usage? Because I do not know if I understand how to use it. I just started to compare myself with these technologies, and I have not found a lot of material to get started.

Comment: Not sure of usage examples for the offline library. For TinCanJava take a look at the unit tests, in particular the `RemoteLRSTest.java` file.